# Configuration file name and version

Tags: iphone, configuration-files

I am developing an application for the iPhone and one of the requests made by the customer is to install a configuration file to force passcode on the device
the requirement is that if the configuration file is not installed then the application will display an alert to the user requesting him to navigate to a specific URL to install it

my question is

How can you check if a configuration file is installed on the iPhone (programmatically) and what version it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here , [Checking whether a configuration profile is installed on iOS](http://alex.tapmania.org/2011/09/check_conf_prof_is_installed_ios.html)

Answer (score 0):

At startup you can check if configuration file already exist in specific folder for example cand stored in Documents .  Version for configuration file cand be stored inside of it

Comment: but configuration file is installed on device level not application level. Can we access this resource? do you have an example?